# Which function is called when application is removed from task manager

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

I need to make status of user offline. When I press home button `onStop()` is called, that's fine. When I press back button `onDestroy()` is invoked. But when I close the app from recent apps by swiping it, `onStop()` or `onDestroy()` isn't called.

I need to know when the app is closed from recent apps to do something (e.g make user offline).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Make a service :

   ```
   public class MyService extends Service {
   private DefaultBinder mBinder;
   private AlarmManager  alarmManager ;
   private PendingIntent alarmIntent;

   private void setAlarmIntent(PendingIntent alarmIntent){
   this.alarmIntent=alarmIntent;
   }

   public void onCreate() {
   alarmManager (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
   mBinder = new DefaultBinder(this);
   }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
     return mBinder;
    }

    public void onTaskRemoved (Intent rootIntent){
    alarmManager.cancel(alarmIntent);
    this.stopSelf();
   }
   }
   ```
2. Make a custom class :

   ```
   public class DefaultBinder extends Binder {
       MyService s;

       public DefaultBinder( MyService s) {
           this.s = s;
       }

       public MyService getService() {
           return s;
       }
   }
   ```
3. Add to your activity :

   ```
   MyService service;
   protected ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
       public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder binder) {
   service = ((DefaultBinder) binder).getService();
   service.setAlarmIntent(pIntent);
       }

       public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
           service = null;
       }
           };

   protected void onResume() {
       super.onResume();
       bindService(new Intent(this, MainService.class), mConnection,
               Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
   }

   @Override
   protected void onStop() {
       super.onStop();

       if (mConnection != null) {
           try {
               unbindService(mConnection);
           } catch (Exception e) {}
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

> But when I close the app from recent apps by swiping it, onStop() or onDestroy() isn't called.

Methods of [`Activity` lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) that are to be called when `Activity` is no longer visible are not guaranteed to be called when removed from the recent tasks (*treat it as "soft" version of killing an app by the system due to low memory*).

> I need to know when the app is closed from recent apps to do something (e.g make user offline)

I suggest one of the following:

- (*If applicable*) use `Activity`'s `onResume()`/`onPause()` to *"make user online/offline"*;
- use [`Service`](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) that [sticks](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_STICKY) to the application meaning that if the app is killed after `Service`'s `onStartCommand()` returns, the service will be recreated and `onStartCommand()` will be called again. At this point you could *"make user offline"*. The chain of lifecycle method calls would be:

  1. `Activity`'s `onStop()` -> `onDestroy()`* ->
  2. `Service`'s `onTaskRemoved()`* ->
  3. `Application`'s `onCreate()` -> `Service`'s `onCreate()` ->
  4. `Service`'s `onStartCommand()`

The `Intent` passed to the method will help you recognize which component triggered the start request:

- `Intent` != null, meaning the request has been received from a running `Activity` instance
- `Intent` = null, meaning the request has been sent by the (newly created) `Application`  instance

---

<sup>* Not guaranteed to be called</sup>

Comment: No @Onik, you can't even use a sticky service because this service will be brutally terminates by the Android OS

Comment: @Attiq ur Rehman ...and after that the service will be recreated. See [START_STICKY](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_STICKY).

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no clean way to get the application termination time. But I could suggest you a dirty trick to use a service to update your application (offline functionalities) for every after n minutes.

When OS kill your application, it will remove all associated services and broadcast receiver along with it.