# Executing method when app is killed on Android

Tags: android, exception, android-lifecycle

I have built an *Android* application. If I terminate my application regularly trough the back button then `onDestroy()` is executed. But when I kill my application (using the recent apps button), `onDestroy()` is never executed. I have now added in the `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` method of my main `Activity` the following:

```
    Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler (new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
        @Override
        public void uncaughtException (Thread thread, Throwable e)
        {
            handleUncaughtException (thread, e);
        }
    });
```

Later in the main `Activity` class I have added:

```
private boolean isUIThread(){
    return Looper.getMainLooper().getThread() == Thread.currentThread();
}

public void handleUncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable e) {
    if(isUIThread()) {
        // exception occurred from UI thread

    } else {  //handle non UI thread throw uncaught exception
        new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //handle non UI thread throw uncaught exception

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, the `handleUncaughtException()` method gets never called when I kill my application (it also gets not called when I regularly terminate my application through the back button).

What is wrong?

I'm using *Android* 5.1.

Comment: How are you killing your application?

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin I'm clicking on the right most button in the navigation bar (there are 3 buttons). This gives me an overview over all running apps. And then I'm making a swipe up to kill all running apps.

Comment: call in OnStop() method

Comment: @deepakp OnStop() gets not called either. onPause() gets called but I don't want to use this because it gets also called when the application only gets to sleep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Unfortunately the `handleUncaughtException()` method gets never called when I kill my application (it also gets not called when I regularly terminate my application through the back button).

[Catching an exception](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler)) (within *dalvik*) and killing an app (*Linux*) process are different things per se. The `handleUncaughtException()` method won't be called in this case, unless the app throws an uncaught exception.

> Executing method when app is killed on Android

When removing an app from recents only `Activity`'s `onPause()` is guaranteed to be called. But you might be "informed" by the `Service`'s callbacks. Some extra info can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35729654/whi%D1%81h-function-is-called-when-application-is-removed-from-task-manger/35729793#35729793) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40072294/when-can-ontaskremoved-be-called/40072391#40072391).